# elasticsearch restart red status

Tags: java, scala, playframework-2.0, elasticsearch

Very basic question regarding the use of Elasticsearch (specifically Java API)

I have a Play! 2 scala application, which on startup starts a node usign myNode.start(). So far so good, and the application is able to index data and search it. on shutdown it calls myNode.close()

However, anytime I restart the application and it tries to access the index, it fails. I print out the ClusterHealthResponse and the status is RED. I get a failure like

```
org.elasticsearch.action.search.SearchPhaseExecutionException: Failed to execute phase [query_fetch], all shards failed
```

The only way I can get the app to run again is if I delete and recreate the index on startup, which is obviously useless since I want to persist the data. The ES documentation, while good at giving deifnitions and describing syntax, seems totally unhelpful in understanding WHAT to do. How do I maintain a usable cluster while persisting data?

**EDIT :**

```
ClusterHealthResponse - status [RED] timedOut [true] clustername [elasticsearch] numberOfNodes [1] numberOfDataNodes [1] activeShards [0] relocatingShards [0] activePrimaryShards [0] initializingShards [0] validationFailures [] indices: [indexname][RED]
```

if I delete and recreate the index:

```
ClusterHealthResponse - status [GREEN] timedOut [false] clustername [elasticsearch] numberOfNodes [2] numberOfDataNodes [2] activeShards [1] relocatingShards [0] activePrimaryShards [1] initializingShards [0] validationFailures [] indices: [indexname][GREEN]
```

Comment: can you post the output from <hostname>:9200/_cluster/health?pretty when it's ok and when you are getting Red status?

Comment: ClusterHealthResponse - status [RED]
timedOut [true]
clustername [elasticsearch]
numberOfNodes [1]
numberOfDataNodes [1]
activeShards [0]
relocatingShards [0]
activePrimaryShards [0]
initializingShards [0]
validationFailures []
indices: [indexname][RED]

\n
if I delete and recreate the index: \n
\n
ClusterHealthResponse - status [GREEN]
timedOut [false]
clustername [elasticsearch]
numberOfNodes [2]
numberOfDataNodes [2]
activeShards [1]
relocatingShards [0]
activePrimaryShards [1]
initializingShards [0]
validationFailures []
indices: [indexname][GREEN]

Comment: I'd rather a take a screenshot already from your elaticsearch-head plug browser page

Comment: @eliasah could you please clarify what you mean?

Comment: [elasticsearch-head](https://github.com/mobz/elasticsearch-head) is a web front end for an Elasticseach cluster. It shows cluster health and allocated shards, etc

Comment: installed elasticsearch-head but the `curl http://localhost:9200/_nodes?plugin=true` shows I have 35 nodes (I think my application is making a new one each time I run it) and all of them show "plugins":[] , so of course `http://localhost:9200/_plugin/head/` just shows a blank page.

Comment: After you restart your cluster you are showing 2 data nodes:  numberOfNodes [2]. This implies that you are actually running more than one instance of ES (either on two different systems or together on one). Any chance you are accidentally creating more nodes? I'd try running http://localhost:9200/_nodes?pretty to get more info on the nodes.

Comment: yes, so I'm actually running 49 separate instances of ES, just with a simple `curl -XGET 'http://localhost:9200/_nodes?pretty' | grep -c 'hostname'`. I guess every time I'm running my app it's spawning new instances and never shutting them down?

Comment: I'm only running one node now, but the problem persists. Also, I got elasticsearch-head to show up once, but since then all I get is a blank page in my browser. I'm also really struggling to find resources on this topic. What's a good way to go about debugging these kinds of issues?

Comment: some more info : ` http://localhost:9200/_cluster/health/?level=shards` returns `{"cluster_name":"elasticsearch","status":"red","timed_out":false,"number_of_nodes":1,"number_of_data_nodes":1,"active_primary_shards":10,"active_shards":10,"relocating_shards":0,"initializing_shards":0,"unassigned_shards":295}`

Comment: So first of all even if you're only running one node now, you were running 49 before. that implies you were also creating new shards too. I think you're probably got a problem with what you are doing in your code, and I'd suggest a next step of sharing your code here in your question.

Comment: have put snippets of the relevant code in a Gist https://gist.github.com/anonymous/cb60c8b5ad9d777c31ec

Comment: also I'm getting conflicting answers, my elasticsearch-head page shows this : http://imgur.com/eA6AF4u but `curl -XGET 'http://localhost:9200/_cluster/health?pretty=true'` shows `{
  "cluster_name" : "elasticsearch",